# How to create a view from PIVOT SQL

Tags: view, pivot, peoplesoft

Our Employee benefits have 5 Plan_Types, I need to put all the data into a view that looks like this:

```
`EMPLID     YEAR   SK   PB   VTO   BV   CT     VC
-----------------------------------------------------
0199990    2017   23   22   5     0    169
0000004    2018   22   0    2          5      65  
0199990    2017   5    34   34    0    55
0000004    2018   23   0    19         5      0  
----------------------------------------------------
```

`
Here is the SQL for the above pivot table

```
`SELECT *  FROM (SELECT b.emplid,
           b.empl_rcd,
           EXTRACT (YEAR FROM B.ACCRUAL_PROC_DT)
               AS year,
           DECODE (b.plan_type,
                   '50', 'SK',
                   '52', 'PB',
                   '5V', 'VTO',
                   '5Y', 'BV',
                   '5Z', 'CT',
                   '51', 'VC')
               BANK,
             B.HRS_CARRYOVER
           + B.HRS_EARNED_YTD
           - B.HRS_TAKEN_YTD
           + B.HRS_ADJUST_YTD
           + B.HRS_BOUGHT_YTD
           - B.HRS_SOLD_YTD
           - B.HRS_TAKEN_UNPROC
           + B.HRS_ADJUST_UNPROC
           + B.HRS_BOUGHT_UNPROC
           - B.HRS_SOLD_UNPROC
               BALANCE
      FROM ps_leave_accrual b)
   PIVOT (SUM (balance) AS bal
         FOR (bank)
         IN ('SK', 'PB', 'VTO', 'BV', 'CT', 'VC'))
```

WHERE emplid in ('0199990','0000004');`

How do I turn this into a view I can use in PS Query.  If I put this code into the view SQL, It fails at the Pivot point - "SQL command not properly ended "

Answer (score 0):

To use non-standard code in views, we have different options:

- We create the record definition and in the SQL we put the SQL, but comment it out, and reference our migration package information. When we build, we build manually as part of the migration process. I've seen folks use DMS to build the views.
- We can create a SQL Object and reference it in the view sql using %SQL(M_CUSTOM_VIEW_SQL), that way the code is migrated with the project.